"Ignore internet and file addresses" not working in spellchecking options
In MS Word we have an option:

Office button > Word options > Proofing > Ignore internet and file
addresses

I have it checked but still get links flagged as typos with the squiggly line etc. I tried unchecking > OK > rechecking. But to no avail.
I even checked the registry at:

\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Proofing
Tools\1.0\Office\IgnoreInternetFileAddresses

and it's set to 1 just as it should be (AFAIK).
Any idea how to get it to ignore links?
